Unable to create and rename a directory according to file version result from WMIC
I am trying to:

Create a new directory.
Rename that directory with the version of a downloaded file.
Move the downloaded file to that directory, (e.g. 125.0.6422.142).

Here is the pertinent code:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Ensure the Temp directory exists
if not exist "C:\Temp" mkdir "C:\Temp"

rem Extract version number from the 32-bit installer
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DATAFILE where "Name=C:\\Temp\\googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi'" GET Version /VALUE') do for /F "delims=" %%H in ("%%G") do set "version=%%H"

rem Create a new folder with the version number
mkdir "C:\Temp\%version%"

rem Move the downloaded files to the version folder
move /Y "C:\Temp\googlechromestandaloneenterprise*.msi" "C:\Temp\%version%\" >nul

rem Notify the user that the download is complete
echo Download complete: C:\Temp\%version%\googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi and C:\Temp\%version%\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi
pause

However, I'm failing to create new directory, and rename that directory according to the version, so that I can move my file there.
Node - MSI-D00084
ERROR:
Description = Invalid query
A subdirectory or file C:\Temp\ already exists.
Download complete: C:\Temp\\googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi and C:\Temp\\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi
Press any key to continue . . .


This is clearly incorrect, "Name=C:\\Temp\\googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi'". Please add the missing singlequote, and try again.

You appear to be checking just one file version and then placing both msi files in the same destination directory. I find it very hard to believe that at all times both the x86 and x64 architecture downloads will carry exactly the vame version number.

Also, even after fixing both of your URL's, which in the pre-edited version above required all of the % characters doubling, neither of the downloaded files have any version information when parsed with WMI. Open a Command Prompt window, type %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DataFile Where "Drive='C:' And Extension='msi' And FileName Like 'GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise%' And Path='\\Temp\\'" Get Name, Version /Value, then press [ENTER]. You will clearly see for yourself! If the command you are using, does not extract the version information, we cannot fix your code.

Here is the output from running the Command Prompt command, I gave in my comment:
C:\>%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DataFile Where "Drive='C:' And Extension='msi' And FileName Like 'GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise%' And Path='\\Temp\\'" Get Name, Version /Value


Name=C:\Temp\googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi
Version=


Name=C:\Temp\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi
Version=




C:\>

This is a courtesy piece of code, just in case anyone wants to verify that I used the OP's own URL's but fixed with double percents, and that the downloaded files do not have Version information to report:
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "BaseDir=%SystemDrive%\Temp"

If Not Exist "%BaseDir%\." MD "%BaseDir%" 2>NUL || (Echo Unable to create the base directory.& Echo Press any key to exit . . .& Pause 1>NUL & Exit /B 1)

%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe -o "%BaseDir%\googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi" "https://dl.google.com/tag/s/appguid%%3D%%7B8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96%%7D%%26iid%%3D%%7B03FE9563-80F9-119F-DA3D-72FBBB94BC26%%7D%%26lang%%3Den%%26browser%%3D4%%26usagestats%%3D0%%26appname%%3DGoogle%%2520Chrome%%26needsadmin%%3Dprefers%%26ap%%3Dx64-stable%%26brand=GCEA/dl/chrome/install/googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi" 
%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe -o "%BaseDir%\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi" "https://dl.google.com/tag/s/appguid%%3D%%7B8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96%%7D%%26iid%%3D%%7B03FE9563-80F9-119F-DA3D-72FBBB94BC26%%7D%%26lang%%3Den%%26browser%%3D4%%26usagestats%%3D0%%26appname%%3DGoogle%%2520Chrome%%26needsadmin%%3Dprefers%%26ap%%3Dx64-stable%%26brand=GCEA/dl/chrome/install/googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi"

Rem This is to show that the downloaded files have no version information.
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DataFile Where "Drive='%BaseDir:~,2%' And Extension='msi' And FileName Like 'GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise%%' And Path='\%BaseDir:~2%\\'" Get Name, Version /Value 2>NUL

Pause

